# Getting error due to item found nil during unwrapping of Optional Value

Tags: swift, xcode, fatal-error

I am trying to add a button that allows the user to refresh the tableview and bring them back to the top of the table. I am trying to add a snippet of code that has a var set up like this `var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!` but it is giving me this message. [image: first image] I then try to run the simulator and simply ignore this message but then I get an error saying it has found an optional value nil when unwrapping it. [image: error message] Any ideas on why this is happening? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Should you be using `let layoutGuide = UILayoutGuide()`

Comment: @byaruhaf I used your method and it ran but now I'm getting this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000538880 "new_app_3.SeeNewPostsButton:0x7fe15853d9f0.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000538f00 "UILayoutGuide:0x6000029e0a80''.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.`

Comment: Note section called Creating Layout Guides: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you for the link, it was great information to take in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `let layoutGuide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide` instead of  `var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide`.